gcovr cant process file
I am trying to generate a some coverage reports using gcov and gcovr, but gcovr fails to process my files.
The compile line for a particular file is the following
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++-11 -DAPP_VERSION=\\\"0.0.0\\\" -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DCore_EXPORTS -DFMT_SHARED -DOPENVDB_DLL -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -I/workspace/src/Mandos/Core/../.. -I/workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/../.. -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/openvdb7d765a96317/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/b/boost4946fa66ec618/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/zlib94980e21071ae/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/onetb4c5f56eddd2b6/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/imath50a3e93596d2e/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/imath50a3e93596d2e/p/include/Imath -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/eigen3d88c0279cc26/p/include/eigen3 -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/tracy3ca493a7de887/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/spdlob47137badbb6c/p/include -isystem /home/dev/.conan2/p/fmt2942afe02511d/p/include -m64 -g -std=c++20 -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden --coverage -O0 -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-semi -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicated-branches -Wlogical-op -Wuseless-cast -Werror -pedantic-errors -o src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/Particle3D.cpp.o -c /workspace/src/Mandos/Core/MechanicalStates/Particle3D.cpp",

I run gcovr with the following command in the build directory (/build/ci-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/)
gcovr --xml-pretty --print-summary -o coverage.xml --root ../../

and I get the following error
(DEBUG) Processing file: /workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/Particle3D.cpp.gcno
(DEBUG) Running gcov: 'gcov --help' in '.'
(DEBUG) Running gcov: 'gcov --help-hidden' in '.'
(DEBUG) Running gcov: 'gcov /workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/Particle3D.cpp.gcno --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --all-blocks --demangled-names --hash-filenames --object-directory .' in '/workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/.'
(ERROR) Trouble processing '/workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/Particle3D.cpp.gcno' with working directory '/workspace/build/ci-x86_64-gcc-11-Debug-gcov/src/Mandos/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/MechanicalStates/.'.

gcvor version es 7.0
I have no clue what I am doing wrong. How should I fix this?

Because your compiler isn't just g++ but /usr/bin/g++-11, there's a good chance things will work better if you pass gcovr the option --gcov-executable /usr/bin/gcov-11. But if that were the problem, I would have expected a slightly different error message…

That works fine! I thought gcov was not strictly tied to a gcc version... Thanks
